# payment for create user account in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, payment, user-accounts

```
many hours i search for it ....could not sucess...please help me out here
```

I am new in magento..i searched a lot but i didn't found anything.. my problem is i want create magento ecommerce site with payment functionality in create account page in magento..
user create account in eCommerce website and upto 5 days user access eCommerce site and after five day this registered user check for payment for access this website..

Any Help Will be appreciated.. 

Thank You,

Comment: Please modify your question according to guidelines written here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist - i.e. write what have you done already, what code have you written, what exactly do you need and what kind of problems have you encountered.